# Dropdown Menu in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, themes

I am new to making WordPress themes but I have managed to include the navigation menu list in my theme. I want to turn it into a horizontal drop-down menu using CSS but I am having all kinds of trouble figuring it out.

I have used this code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

To output this:

```
    <div id="nav-container">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">Current Page</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-58">Menu Item #1
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-62">Child Item #1</li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-60">Child Item #2</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Can someone please tell me, or point me in the right direction for turning this into a drop down menu? As a note I do not know how to change the way the nav list is output either :(.

I know this might be a big ask but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of docs and examples available: http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus and http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 1):

Making dropdown menus in wordpress with their "menus" in the dashboard is extremely easy. You can simply make your menu and indent any of the items you would want inside a dropdown by simply dragging it a little bit to the right (it snaps into place) and wordpress by default will add the `.dropdown` class that you can then style with CSS however you want.

If you need help beyond that with the CSS then it's probably a good idea to learn how to make CSS dropdown menus so you can compliment it with this.

Cheers.